# Python - applying concat function for two rows in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data frame which is basically an image id and a set of biological features. I have to combine all the IDs(the GIDs) and the resulting features should be concatenation of all the rows with the same ID.

I do understand the solution will require use of `group_by` function with an apply to rows that I need to concat to. I am not sure of the function argument to write in this case.

Sample data.

```
df[['GID','AID','INDIVIDUAL_NAME','NID']].head(10)
        GID    AID INDIVIDUAL_NAME    NID 
    0   546  16167            ____ -16167 
    1   546  16168            ____ -16168 
    2   546  16169            ____ -16169 
    3   546  16170            ____ -16170 
    4  5666  13822   IBEIS_PZ_1866   2139 
    5  5713   9269   NNP_GIRM_0149    253 
    6  8838  11554   IBEIS_PZ_0373    646 
    7  1062   9439   NNP_GIRM_0143    234 
    8  1062   9440            ____  -9440 
    9  7748   9253            ____  -9253
```

I need the resulting output as

```
    GID    AID                       INDIVIDUAL_NAME         NID
0   546  16167,16168 ,16169,16170    ____, ____, ____, ____  -16167,-16168 ,-16169,-16170 
1  5666  13822                       IBEIS_PZ_1866           2139
2  5713   9269                       NNP_GIRM_0149           253                     frontleft
3  8838  11554                       IBEIS_PZ_0373           646  
4  1062   9439,9440                  NNP_GIRM_0143, ____     234,-9440 
5  7748   9253                       ____                   -9253
```

Also, I am look for a good tutorial where they have explained apply function for pandas data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first cast to `string` and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column `GID` and [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) function `join`:

```
df['AID'] = df.AID.astype(str)
df['NID'] = df.NID.astype(str)

print (df.groupby('GID').agg(','.join).reset_index())
    GID                      AID      INDIVIDUAL_NAME  \
0   546  16167,16168,16169,16170  ____,____,____,____   
1  1062                9439,9440   NNP_GIRM_0143,____   
2  5666                    13822        IBEIS_PZ_1866   
3  5713                     9269        NNP_GIRM_0149   
4  7748                     9253                 ____   
5  8838                    11554        IBEIS_PZ_0373   

                           NID  
0  -16167,-16168,-16169,-16170  
1                    234,-9440  
2                         2139  
3                          253  
4                        -9253  
5                          646
```

[Groupby aggregation in docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation).

EDIT:

Alternatively you can use `astype` with `join`:

```
print (df.groupby('GID').agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index())
    GID                      AID      INDIVIDUAL_NAME  \
0   546  16167,16168,16169,16170  ____,____,____,____   
1  1062                9439,9440   NNP_GIRM_0143,____   
2  5666                    13822        IBEIS_PZ_1866   
3  5713                     9269        NNP_GIRM_0149   
4  7748                     9253                 ____   
5  8838                    11554        IBEIS_PZ_0373   

                           NID  
0  -16167,-16168,-16169,-16170  
1                    234,-9440  
2                         2139  
3                          253  
4                        -9253  
5                          646
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Can you also help me with a link where I can find explanation to operations like `agg` on data frames?

Comment: Yes, give me a sec.

Comment: I add link to docs, there is function `aggregate` and it is same as `agg`. I think `agg` is using more, because it is shorter and has less letters.

Comment: Saw that. I greatly appreciate your response. Thank you.